# Meaning of "mi cabo"

Tags: modismos

It's used while speaking indians (mexicans?) in a book of Mario Vargas Llosa. I am interested about origin and meaning of this phrase. Contextual it should mean something like "my friend", but it's only my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"**Cabo**" is a rank of military hierarchy, equivalent to "corporal" in Anglo-Saxon culture. The use of the possessive "**mi**" corresponds to a respectful manner, as in "Oh, captain! **My** captain!".

Comment: Rodrigo, we really don't say Anglo-Saxon in English, unless it refers to early settlers in in England who came over from the Europe.  We say: English-speaking cultures.

Answer (score -1):

military rank corporal or between corporal and sergeant (cabo primero). I guess you're reading "La ciudad y los perros". I studied in that place...